# ASP.Net MVC Form action in returned View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

Will keep this as simple a possible:-

I have a have a controller which will return either ViewA or ViewB - e.g.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ViewA(BlahModel model)
{
    if (isTrue)
      return View(model);
    else
      return View("ViewB", model);
}
```

...

The problem I have is that ViewB has a form on it. And what happens is that if it gets returned, the action attribute of the  tag still points to ViewA.

```
/MyControllerName/ViewA
```

I thought I could do something like this:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("ViewB","MyControllerName"))
```

But this returns the following URL in the markup:

```
/ViewB?action=ViewB&amp;controller=MyControllerName
```

How can I get the HTML Helper to correctly return the following?

```
/MyControllerName/ViewB
```

Many thanks

**UPDATE**

This was indeed caused by some ugly legacy routing from when the project was half-way between WebForms and MVC

Comment: What HTML is rendered in ViewB? Does the form in ViewB have action="get"

Comment: What does `<%= Url.Action("ViewB", "MyControllerName") %>` generate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's issue in routing table. Routing engine can't find route statisfies this action\controller and simply put theese parameters to querystring.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have an action named `ViewB`?  If not, the routing engine can't understand what you're asking for and appends extra variables to the querystring for the target.  One action that renders two different views is fine, but if you want `ViewB` to `POST` somewhere different than `ViewA`, then you need an action in your controller for `ViewB`.

EDIT:  Further clarification, if the `ViewA` **action** should always be called, then you don't need a `ViewB` **action**, and your `ViewB` **view** should just post back to the `ViewA` **action**.

If the `ViewB` **view** needs to execute a different **action** than your `ViewA` **view**, then you need to create another **action** for `ViewB` to `POST` to.

Sorry for all the bold, but I just wanted to be clear about the differences between actions and views.